# Error while setting ManualResetEvent on callback mock setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, manualresetevent

I am making use of `ManualResetEvent` class in a test.

Basically, I want to invoke the `Set()` method when a particular function is called. 
This looks like:

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
mockObj.Setup(dmc => dmc.Foo(param1, param2, param3)).Callback(mre.Set()); //Error here.
```

However, I get an error saying:

> **Cannot convert from bool to 'System.Action'**

when I try to set the `mre`.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all

> **Cannot convert from bool to 'System.Action'**

`Callback` requires a lambda expression / Action

```
//...
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
mockObj
    .Setup(dmc => dmc.Foo(param1, param2, param3))
    .Callback(() => mre.Set()); //<-- Callback requires an Action
//...
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better under standing of how to use the mocking framework.